# Visualising a table of proportions

Tags: logistic, data-visualization, proportion

I have a table like

```
            Arts   Science  Medicine Engineering
Male   0.5476190 0.7663551 0.6436364   0.7253521
Female 0.8025478 0.9508197 0.0000000   0.0000000
```

were the entries are proportions survived after 50 years, i.e. 0.547... of Male Arts students survived after 50 years. No women studied Medicine and Engineering. I'm looking for a way to visualise this data.

Sidenote: This is motivated by a logistic regression I ran modeling logit(survival probability) on sex and university faculty. My result was logit(p)= 0.49 + 0.49*Engineering + 0.27*Medicine + 0.61*Science - 0.72*Male. Any thoughts on visualising that?

Answer (score 2):

A dot chart or bar chart springs to mind.

I have a bias to table-bar chart hybrids where numbers are shown detectably (so no scale is needed).

[image]

Here is a (Cleveland) dot chart. As with the display just given I am regarding the zeros as in effect missing. It's not that no females survived, but that there were no females to start with.

With a dot chart I don't feed the need to start the numeric axis at zero. Also, in this take, alphabetical order is sacrificed in favour of sorting on the outcome.

[image]

EDIT: I added a frame as suggested by @whuber and @gung.

[image]

Comment: This plot seems ambiguous to me in that I can't see where the top possible level of the bar is supposed to be, so I can't really see that a bar is 75% of the way to the top or only 50% of the way.  Of course, the numbers alleviate that issue, but then, why plot the bars at all?

Comment: Good point. Naturally, you can always show a scale with more conventional designs. Cleveland proposed thermometer charts in which the maximum was shown explicitly.

Comment: Nick, the comment by @gung is well grounded in data visualization theory.  By erecting faint but visible indicators of where 1.000 lies in each row--perhaps by use of horizontal lines--you can help the audience read the bar heights more quickly with greater accuracy.  A variant of a thermometer chart is a good idea.  You might also apply Tufte's principle of minimizing the data-ink ratio to redesign this chart, which would lead quickly to a thermometer-like rendering of each box.  You could also devote the bar widths to the visual representation of the actual counts in each category.

Comment: If the counts were given, and they are not, then something like a mosaic plot could work well.

Comment: I ultimately settled on a mosaic plot using the counts, however, a plot using proportions was ideal.